# Are the cables for a PS Vita Charger proprietary to Sony?

Tags: hardware, ps-vita

Just recently I learned that the black casing around the PC End of the USB Part of the PS Vita Charger had started to come off and expose some wires. this has gotten me concerned as my only other way to play PS Vita Games is a PS TV and not all of my Vita Games will work on it.

The charger comes in 3 parts. a USB Cable that plugs into the Vita, a power cable and the little box....thing that the USB and Power cable connects two.

Now I assume that the little box thing is something I can only buy from Sony are the cables themselves proprietary to Sony? if not what names would I use for them if I was to search for where to buy them?

Comment: I only own the original Vita (which has a proprietary charging port instead of USB), so I can't give you a definitive answer, but I know that at least the "box" part is not necessary to charge the Vita.

Comment: @Nolonar if you're talking about PC charging with the USB i have read that the amperage from a PC USB Port isn't high enough for the Vita to charge while it's on (which alot of the time i am charging while playing)

Comment: I don't see why not; the Vita I got came with a glorified USB charger.  I use it more to charge my phone than I do the Vita itself; it's a pretty high powered outlet to USB; 2.4A.

Comment: Go to your favourite online reseler and search "PS Vita charger"

Answer (score 2):

The Vita 1000 series cable is a Sony proprietary cable. Unfortunately Sony only sells replacement of the power brick part of the cable on it's own. They do not seem to sell the cable that connects from the power brick to the system. There are third-party companies that sell the cable on-line (eg, Amazon, NewEgg, GameStop, Walmart) for $5-$20. Try to stick to an establish brand if you can because quality varies. You could also try checking any used video game stores who might have a used cable salvaged from a dead system.